# Toast message is not displayed at the right time?

Tags: android, android-toast

I need to display "Wait a moment..." message via Toast while the app tries to fetch some data from the internet that can take couples of seconds depending on the internet connection and the load on the server.
the http connection is made through a AsyncTask.

What I am doing is that I display the message by : "Toast.makeText" method, then I enter a "while" loop that breaks when the execute method of the AsyncTask finishes, then I display some results on the Activity.

The problem is that the Toast dosen't appear until the while loop breaks!
I tried to replace the Toast with displaying the message in TextView with setText , but the same happened, the message displayed after the while loop breaks!
any thoughts? My Code looks like this:

```
waitToast = Toast.makeText(this,R.string.WaitText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);             
  waitToast.show();
    .........
    .........

new DownloadFilesTask().execute();

dataRetrieved = false;
while (!dataRetrieved){   }
    ........
```

And in the doInBackground:

```
   private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {

        InputStream in = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {


            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(4000);

            in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            url_input = readStream(in);
            ........



    catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


        }

        finally{
            dataRetrieved = true;
            urlConnection.disconnect();
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Call it in `onPreExecute()` method.

Comment: you have to complete operation in ui thread. it is bad practice that waiting asyntask end in ui thread. you dont get any advantages of asyntask in this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not do this.  You are blocking the ui thread with your while loop. That's why your Toast does not show up.

Remove your while and  override onPostExecute()  in your AsyncTask. This methods runs on the Ui thread, unlike doInbackground so you can update Activity UI.

Answer (score 0):

use this method in asynktask:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    // Show Toast
    Toast.makeText(context,"text",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

And remember "onPostExecute" and "onPreExecute" Can Change UI , Don't Change UI At "doInBackground" .

Comment: OK, thank you all very much, I got it. onPostExecute and onPreExecute  works on UI. I didn't know that.